# Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: DEFAULT keyword cannot be used as column has no DEFAULT Exception IN JUNit

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I am getting below exception in JUNITS:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: DEFAULT keyword cannot be used as
>   column has no DEFAULT

My code looks like the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

In my base entity class and rest all entities extends this base entity.

The code runs fine but while in JUNITs, but I am getting the exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Formatted the code

Comment: This exception is thrown by older versions of HSQLDB. The latest HSQLDB 2.3.4 does not throw the exception.

Comment: This is giving new exception on the same lines .

The database returned no natively generated identity value